# What does the $\sigma_z$ operator correspond to in the context of a Transmon qubit?

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

In the context of the transmon qubit and an LC circuit with a coupling capacitor and driving voltage.

We can write the charge operator $Q$ as $-iQ_{ZPF}\sigma_y$ (since we defined $Q$ using the ladder operators $a$ and $a^+$). Similarly we can do the same for the magnetic flux operator $\Phi$ in terms of $\sigma_x$. What $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ represent make sense to me conceptually since they correspond to observables.

But can we do the same for $\sigma_z$? I am asking this since I was reading this [paper](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/theses/Sank2014.pdf) that was writing the driving Hamiltonian as $H_d=\dfrac{Q_{ZPF}V_0f(t)\sigma_y}{1+C/C_d}$ (Eq D.19 Pg 190).

And it also states that the single qubit Hamiltonian for single nearly harmonic qubits like the transmon is: $\dfrac{H_q}{\hbar}=-\dfrac{\omega_q}{2}\sigma_z$ (Eq D.38 Pg 196).

But what does this Hamiltonian mean? Or how can we prepare a qubit in such a state that it would correspond to this Hamiltonian?